# angularjs components getting a form inside template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

so I have a component with a template containing a form.

mycomponent.html:

```
<div>
    <form name="myForm"> 
        <!-- more html code -->
    </form>
</div>
```

How can I access myForm inside the component controller?
Currently I'm injecting $scope to get it from that. 
Or is that the only way to get the form?

Edit: Added some code to better illustrate in javascript

```
angular.module('example')
.component('myComponent', {

    templateUrl: 'mycomponent.html',
    controller: function($scope) {
         $scope.myForm // This works
         this.myForm // undefined, can I access it through the component scope instead of $scope somehow? 
    }
 });
```

Comment: Generally you bind you the elements in the form in angular, rather than dealing with the form directly.  Is there some reason you need to access the form element itself?

Comment: I wanted to check the $pristine, $valid e.t.c.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `name` attribute of a form is what angular uses to decide what to bind to.  So, if you're using the controllerAs syntax, you have to use that in the form name:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
    <form name='vm.myForm'>
    </form>
  </body>
```

This will allow you to refer to it in your controller without using $scope, but only after the controller has been successfully created:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {

    var vm = this;

    console.log(vm.myForm);  // undefined

    $timeout(function() {
        console.log(vm.myForm);  // FormController object
    }, 100);
});
```

Here is a working [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/DugdzrLhgTH1qAVBpXSd).

Comment: Thanks, that worked with a slight modification since I'm using components and don't have access to as far as I know "mainctrl as vm".

    <form name='$ctrl.myForm'>

as the name and then accessable as this in the angular component.

Comment: Are you using angular 1.5?  It automatically adds `$ctrl` as a default value for `controllerAs`, even for components.

Comment: Yes, angular 1.5 and I see. Good to know for the future!

Comment: Yes this <form name='$ctrl.myForm'> works for components but as royka pointed out you can access that in postLink hook

Comment: I do not approve of `$timeout` usage, when it can be handled by a simple scope function from template and have a form for an argument there. More complex example [here](https://jsbin.com/noqacu/3/edit?html,js,console).

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure there's a better way to wait until the controller has been created to do stuff like that.

Comment: @Dave there is a .$onInit function for components that is for use to run after the component is initialized and ready for use, so using this example `vm.$onInit => () { console.log(vm.myForm);}`

Answer (score 1):

Use the name syntax but also a components postLink lifecycle hook, that function is called once a template and controller have been connected see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component